# Params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my project I got a view, in this view I have a date input like this:

```
<%= form_tag installations_path, :method => :csv, :class => 'form-search' do %>
<%= select_date(date = Date.current, options = {}, html_options = {}) %>
<%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller Installation I got a method with the name "csv" this method generate a Csv. Example:

```
def csv
  @consumption = current_user.get_consumptions(params[:year])
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @consumption.to_csv }
  end
end
```

When I execute the view I receive this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: installation
```

The problem is that in my installations_params I have require(:installation) cause I use object installation in others methods.

```
def installation_params
    params.require(:installation).permit(:year,...)
end
```

What is the best way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is correct, if you do not call the installation_params, you should not have any problem. Maybe some code is missing ?

Comment: have you had a look at the request header?

Answer (score 1):

1. The request log may help you firstly.
2. If you generate the csv as a GET request, then change the code

   from:

   ```
   <%= form_tag installations_path, :method => :csv, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <%= form_tag csv_installations_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   ```

   Make sure the `csv_installations_path` is exist.
3. Then, you can get the `year` params as `params[:year]` if your input named `year`.
4. At last, You don't use any `install_params` in csv method

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The page refresh and the url change but nothing happens, the csv is not generated.

Comment: I try create variables in controller like year to test if the csv is generated and I use `<%= link_to "CSV", csv_installations_path(format: "csv") %>` in view to test. This works, the csv is generated. So now I want to do this thing with params. @dinglixiang